# Issue with sending direct message to someone with API for Twitter

Tags: php, twitter

Hey guys I am using the following:

```
function confirm($x, $y)
{
    $inerlevelWatch = $x;
    $NewDirectMessage = $y;
    $directmessconect = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $currentTwitteroauth, $currentTwitteroauthsecret);
    $parameters = array('screen_name' => $inerlevelWatch, 'text' => $NewDirectMessage);
    $method = 'direct_messages/new';
    $directmessconect->post($method, $parameters);
}
```

So I give the `$innerlevelWatch` a screen_name so lets say, `Joe` and than the new direct message that is passed to `$NewDirectMessage` = '`testing`'.  I create new connection just for the sending of the message inside this function and set the parameters.  Set the method and then make the post.

The issue is, It does not seem to actually send and I am not sure why, so if you could give me a hand I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
`$consumerKey="your consumerKey";
$consumerSecret ="consumerSecret";
$accessToken ="accessToken ";
$accessTokenSecret ="accessTokenSecret";`
```

// Create object

```
`$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken,   $accessTokenSecret);`
```

// Set status message

```
`$tweetMessage="message";`
`$scrren_name='abc';`

`if(strlen($tweetMessage)<=140)
{
$tweet->post('direct_messages/new', array('screen_name' => $scrren_name,'text'=>$tweetMessage));

}`
```

hope it help you